# Transmit array as first parameter in web3.js

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, javascript

When I develop in solidity combined with web3.js, I face some problem recently. I create a contract code below

```
//setContractDetail(index,bool isConsentItem,uint8[] detailItems)
function setContractDetail(uint8 index,bool isConsentItem,uint8[] detailItems) public checkOwner{
    consentForm.items[index].isConsent= isConsentItem;
    consentForm.items[index].itemDetail = detailItems;
    /* emit SetContractDetailEvent(msg.sender,index,isConsentItem,detailItems,now); */
}
function setContractDetail2(uint8 index,bool isConsentItem) public checkOwner{
    consentForm.items[index].isConsent = isConsentItem;
}
function setContractDetail3(uint8[] index,bool isConsentItem,uint8[] detailItems) public checkOwner{
    for(uint i=0;i<index.length;i++){
        uint pointer = index[i];
        consentForm.items[pointer].isConsent= isConsentItem;
        consentForm.items[pointer].itemDetail = detailItems;
    }
    /* emit SetContractDetailEvent(msg.sender,index,isConsentItem,detailItems,now); */
}
function setContractDetail4(bool isTest,uint8[] index,bool isConsentItem,uint8[] detailItems) public checkOwner{
    for(uint i=0;i<index.length;i++){
        uint pointer = index[i];
        consentForm.items[pointer].isConsent= isConsentItem;
        consentForm.items[pointer].itemDetail = detailItems;
    }
    /* emit SetContractDetailEvent(msg.sender,index,isConsentItem,detailItems,now); */
}
```

When I pass the first parameter as an array (setContractDetail3), I always get an error-message - **ERROR Error: Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction**. However, when I set non-array value as first parameter, the function call will be well performed. Does anyone know what is the reason for this issue?

> p.s I could successfully compile on the remix, but after I set the contract in geth console as well as connecting with web3.js, it ultimately get fail.

Comment: Did you set the Gas and GasPrice when calling the smart contract method?

Comment: I use "Mycontract.methods.mymethod(parms).estimateGas({from:account}).then()" to set up my gas value. On the other hand, I set my gasPrice as 0 (I use geth to set up -gasPrice 0 when activating the console)

Comment: I still dont know what is the reason of the error; but your estimate gas call like this `estimateGas({from:account})` is not sufficient because it lacked much of information to estimate gas. You should provide enough information as below

Comment: ```
// CallMsg contains parameters for contract calls.
type CallMsg struct {
 From     common.Address  // the sender of the 'transaction'
 To       *common.Address // the destination contract (nil for contract creation)
 Gas      uint64          // if 0, the call executes with near-infinite gas
 GasPrice *big.Int        // wei <-> gas exchange ratio
 Value    *big.Int        // amount of wei sent along with the call
 Data     []byte          // input data, usually an ABI-encoded contract method invocation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use dynamic arrays as a function argument using ABIEncoderV2 to a solidity function.

Refer the following Github issue and blog for more details -

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2708

https://blog.ricmoo.com/solidity-abiv2-a-foray-into-the-experimental-a6afd3d47185

However, using multiple dynamic arrays as an argument might be another issue because in  Java a variable length argument must be the last argument of a function and using multiple variable length arguments in the same function is not allowed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error **always failing transaction** is what applies here - if you pass an array as the value, unless the structure of `consentForm.items` is exactly identical to the array being passed, the transaction will search for, for example, "randomStringThatIUsedToNameTheFirstItemInMyArray", and compare it to whatever items[0] is denoted as. This will probably fail and your function will become stuck in a loop - i.e. **always failing transaction**.

Besides this reason, I would restructure the contract, as loops like this are always

a) risky
b) gas heavy

...and probably use a try/catch block in the loop in case of such an error.